# Rails twitter gem adding twitter data to rails database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, twitter, omniauth

so I used omniauth to allow users to sign into Twitter. Their data is passed into the User model and database. This is turn creates a new session with a `current_user` based on the Omniauth data. I installed the twitter gem, and saved the config info in a method called `twitter_client`. In the view, I then called the 'followers' method on the `twitter_client` using the current_user's twitter name from the database, to display the followers of the user than signed in.

I would like to know how I go about storing the user's followers in a database, and then displaying the followers in the view from the database, rather than directly from twitter. I know it involves iterating over the current_user followers in a model (I created a follower.rb model and a followers controller). But it is the intricacies of linking it all together I am struggling with.

Current view `index.html.erb`

```
 <div class="twitter_list">
          <p id="list_title">Followers of <%= current_user.name %>:</p>
          <% twitter_client.followers(current_user.twitter_user_name).each do        |follower| %>
            <p><%= follower.name %></p>
            <hr>
          <% end %>
        </div>
```

User Model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def self.from_omniauth(auth_hash)
  #Look up the user or create them using keys in the auth hash
  user = where(provider: auth_hash.provider, uid: auth_hash.uid).first_or_create
  user.update(
  name: auth_hash.info.name,
  profile_image: auth_hash.info.image,
  twitter_user_name: auth_hash.info.nickname,
  token: auth_hash.credentials.token,
  secret: auth_hash.credentials.secret
 )
  user
end
```

Application Controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

  def twitter_client
    @client ||= Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
    config.consumer_key        = Rails.application.secrets.twitter_api_key
    config.consumer_secret     = Rails.application.secrets.twitter_api_secret
    config.access_token        = current_user.token
    config.access_token_secret = current_user.secret
  end
 end

# to enable the current_user variable to be used in the view file
helper_method :current_user, :twitter_client
```

end

Sessions Controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    # complete omniauth authentication and crate user record in database
    # raise env["omniauth.auth"].to_yaml

  @user = User.from_omniauth(auth_hash)
  session[:user_id] = @user.id
  redirect_to root_path
end

def destroy
  session[:user_id] = nil
  redirect_to root_path, notice: "You are signed out"
end

protected

def auth_hash
  request.env['omniauth.auth']
end
```

end

Current attempt at a Followers controller and Follower Model (not sure how to proceed):

```
class FollowersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @followers = Follower.all
  end

  def new
    @followers = Follower.new
  end

  def create
    @followers = Follower.new(post_params)
  end

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:followers).permit(:followers)
  end
end


class Follower < ApplicationRecord

  twitter_client.followers(current_user.twitter_user_name).each do |follower|
    follower.name
  end

end
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. The code snippets feature is only for client side code - javascript, css and html. It lets you create examples that the user can run. For server side languages such as ruby you should use code blocks instead. Select the code and press the `{}` button on the toolbar.

Comment: cheers - all changed

Answer (score 0):

Lets start with the basic problem:

> Displaying the users followers without fetching it from Twitter every
>   time.

Create a database entity for each follower might not actually be the best solution here - it's data that is not really yours and your users will not be editing the resource. It also adds the need of keeping your database in sync with twitter.

Having a model which represents followers in your app is still a good idea though as it lets you do normalisation and use the translation API for example. It also serves to isolate your application from changes in the external API.

**So lets create a `Follower` [model that is not backed by the database](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Model.html). Populate it with data from twitter. And use caching to avoid the twitter api query.**

```
# note that it should not inherit from ActiveRecord::Base
class Follower 
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :twitter_uid, :name, :screen_name
end
```

### Fetching data

So what we want to do is get the data from twitter and use it create model instances - a good pattern for this is creating a service:

```
# app/services/followers_service.rb
module FollowersService
  def self.call(user, client: nil)
    client = client || self.twitter_client(user)
    followers = twitter_client.followers(current_user.twitter_user_name)
    followers.map do |raw|
      # @todo check the actual response from Twitter
      Follower.new do |f|
        f.twitter_uid  = raw["id"]
        f.name         = raw["name"]
        f.screen_name  = raw["screen_name"]
      end
    end
  end

  private 
    def self.twitter_client(user)
      def twitter_client
       secrets = Rails.application.secrets
       Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
         config.consumer_key        = secrets.twitter_api_key
         config.consumer_secret     = secrets.twitter_api_secret
         config.access_token        = user.token
         config.access_token_secret = user.secret
      end
    end
end
```

We can now test it in isolation by calling `FollowersService.call(User.first)`. The extra client param lets us inject a double to easily fake the twitter response in tests.

### Caching the result.

One way of caching the response would be to use fragment caching if we where for example displaying the followers in a sidebar:

```
<%= cache("user-{current_user.id}-followers", expires_in: 1.day)  do %>
  <% FollowersService.call(current_user).each do |f| %>
    <%= f.name %>
  <% end %> 
<% end %>
```

Which caches the rendered view. If you are using the data in a bunch of different places you might want to use [low level caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#low-level-caching) instead:

```
@followers = Rails.cache.fetch("user-{current_user.id}-followers", expires_in: 12.hours) do
  FollowersService.call(current_user)
end
```

### What about the controller?

Do you really need a separate controller for Followers? If you really need a route to display the followers or get the data for ajax you could create a simple controller:

```
class FollowersController
  # GET /followers
  def index
    @followers = Rails.cache.fetch("user-{current_user.id}-followers", expires_in: 12.hours) do
      FollowersService.call(current_user)
    end
  end
end
```

You don't need the whole rails CRUD set of actions since the data is fetched from an external source and not created/modified by users.